# Positive matrix times positive vector

Tags: matrices

If **A** is a $k \times k$ positive definite matrix and **b** is $k \times 1$ vector, are all elements in **A b** always positive?

Comment: What is a positive vector?

Comment: I meant a vector with all elements are positive.

Comment: Consider this: if $A$ is positive definite, and has full rank, then for an arbitrary $b$, the entries of $Ab$ are also arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.

Here is an example:

$$A =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\mathbf{b} =\begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-}0  \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$A\mathbf{b} =\begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-}0  \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{matrix}\right)$ and $v=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$. I will leave it to you to prove that above the reals $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks enrenches